# Drawing and labeling the axes for the Cartesian plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Nothing exciting here.  I only have code to display the coordinate axes.  I have a file in which displays of various functions are plotted on the Cartesian plane and displays of a pair of intersecting lines, a triangle, a parallelogram, or some other polygon is drawn on the Cartesian plane.  The axes are labeled `x`  and `y`.  In the case in which functions are plotted, the specifications

```
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west}
```

and

```
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
```

are used in the `axis` environment to label the axes.  In the case in which lines or polygons are drawn, a node command is issued.  I want the positioning of the `x` and `y` to be consistent.

In the following code, only the axes are drawn.  I position the `x` with the following commands.

```
\coordinate (x-label) at ($(5,0) +({1em*0.6},-0.6em)$);
\node[red] at (x-label){$x$};
```

I position the `y` with the following commands.

```
\coordinate (y-label) at ($(0,5) +({1em*(2/3)},{1em*(2/3)})$);
\node[red] at (y-label){$y$};
```

They do not position the `x` and `y` exactly over the `x` and `y` from the `axis` environment.  Why is a horizontal and vertical shift of `1em*0.6` "close" to getting the right fit for `x` but `{1em*(2/3)` is close to getting the right fit for `y`?  How do I get `x` and `y` to be consistently positioned in this file?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-1.5,ymax=5,
    restrict y to domain=-1.5:5,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\draw[latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\coordinate (x-label) at ($(5,0) +({1em*0.6},-0.6em)$);
\node[red] at (x-label){$x$};
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-1.5) -- (0,5);
\coordinate (y-label) at ($(0,5) +({1em*(2/3)},{1em*(2/3)})$);
\node[red] at (y-label){$y$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is essentially the same question you've asked twice before. If you would read the `pgfplots` manual, I do think it would make more sense. Page 350 is quite illuminating.

Comment: @cfr  I have looked at page 350 of the manual at the following web site: `http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf`.  It is almost a blank page.

Comment: That is the manual for TikZ/PGF. It is not the manual for `pgfplots`. As people keep explaining, what you are seeing is an effect of the `axis` environment. That is provided by `pgfplots`. Page 350 is the start of the section on TikZ Interoperability. It tells you about the capacity for, and restrictions on, use of ordinary TikZ stuff, especially with respect to coordinate systems which are *not* the same.

Comment: Though in this case, I doubt this has much to do with `pgfplots`. This just looks like the usual slight imprecisions to me. The red and black are not perfectly aligned. Or is the question why you need different values? Where do the values come from? Just trial-and-error?

Comment: @cfr  I added `anchor=origin` to the `axis` environment, and I use `({1em*(2/3)},{-1em*(2/3)})` to position the `x` with respect to the point `(5,0)` and `({1em*(2/3)},{1em*(2/3)})`  to position the `y` with respect to the point `(0,5)`.  Both labels are almost aligned.  (The alignment of the `y` is much closer than the alignment of the `x`.)  I do not know why `anchor=origin` made the alignment so much better.

Comment: @cfr  I was told that the inner separation associated with `at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}` is `0.6666em`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do this particularly but you can get them consistently positioned by specifying them in the same way as you do for the `axis` environment:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      width=5in,
      axis equal image,
      clip=false,
      axis lines=middle,
      xmin=-5,
      xmax=5,
      ymin=-1.5,
      ymax=5,
      restrict y to domain=-1.5:5,
      xtick={\empty},
      ytick={\empty},
      axis line style={latex-latex},
      xlabel=$x$,
      ylabel=$y$,
      xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
      ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west},
    ]
    \draw[latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw[latex-latex] (0,-1.5) -- (0,5);
    \node [red, anchor=south west] at (0,5) {$y$};
    \node [red, anchor=north west] at (5,0) {$x$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Something like 2/3 is always going to involve a certain imprecision but, in general, TikZ/PGF has limited precision because it is implemented in TeX.

[image: co-located axis labels]

Comment: I agree.  The black and red `x` are aligned, and the black and red `y` are aligned.  (I thought that the `x` and `y` would be typeset in red because those commands are given last.)  Is the inner separation for the node associated with `at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west` supposed to be two-thirds of an `em`?  When manually input into the code via `{1em*(2/3)}`, are you saying that `TeX` rounds it to a different value than what is calculated via `anchor=north west`?

Comment: @user74973 I don't know if it is meant to be that or not. But if you get to the same place by different routes, you will often not get to *quite* the same place because the calculations cannot be that precise.

Comment: @user74973 About the colour, presumably the black labels are being added after the red. This will have to do with the order in which `pgfplots` does things, I assume.